# Duplicate Columns appearing in data grid

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Hi I am populating a grid on a form from a data table using the following code

```
      FormDataSet = woutil.GetDataSet;
      dgComments.DataDource = FormDataSet.Tables["COMMENT"];
      foreach(DataColumn col in FormDataSet.Tables["COMMENT"].Columns)
      {
          dgComments.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
      }
```

The table COMMENT has only 4 columns

The FormDataSet is an empty data set at the time the code is invoked. When the code has run there is a table COMMENT with 4 columns in the table.

The dgComments DataGridView has no cloumns or data source prior to calling the code.

This code does create the columns in the grid however instead of the 4 columns I was expecting there are 8 columns because the columns are duplicated. Please can someone let me know what I have done wrong and advise how I can populate the grid so that only the 4 columns are showing. If I step the code the Add is only called 4 times so I cannot see why there are 8 columns added??

At a later date I will be changing the code so that only certain columns are added to the grid but at this stage I am happy to display all of the columns

Comment: did you change [`DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) from default true?

Comment: Did you try to remove the foreach loop?

Comment: Hi Steve thanks for the fast response to be honest I just dragged the grid from the tool box and didn't change any properties so if the AutoGenerateColumns is set to true by default that may be the issue. Unfortunately I am not able to check this as I have not got access to the PC it is on at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably just neglected to set AutoGenerateColumns false.

If that's the case then when you set the DataSource property on this line:

```
dgComments.DataSource = FormDataSet.Tables["COMMENT"];
```

The Columns are automatically being generated for you by .Net.

When you iterate over the table and add the columns based on the columns in the table you're duplicating them.  If you want to manually control the columns then try this:

```
FormDataSet = woutil.GetDataSet;
dgComments.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgComments.DataSource = FormDataSet.Tables["COMMENT"];
foreach(DataColumn col in FormDataSet.Tables["COMMENT"].Columns)
{
    dgComments.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ColumnName);
}
```